# What is the block maturity value seen in many pool interfaces?

Tags: mining-pools, transaction-confirmation

[image: monerohash.com screenshot]

As you can see in this screenshot, a column called "Maturity" is shown on most mining pools' found blocks table. I did my best to find an answer to my own question with keywords such as "monero block maturity" or "cryptonote block maturity", but couldn't find anything.

It seems like a certain number of steps or confirmations needed when a block is found by a pool (I guess it's the same when mining solo), but I can't be sure.

Sub questions: this value obviously goes from x to zero. What's the value of x, and is it always the same? EDIT: Ok, just saw the "Maturity Depth Requirement" in my own screenshot... sorry! Still, this original question remains. ;-)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It seems like a certain number of steps or confirmations needed when a block is found by a pool (I guess it's the same when mining solo), but I can't be sure.

This is exactly right. When a block is mined, it cannot be spent until 60 blocks after it has been mined (with a 2 minute block time, this means roughly 2 hours). The same applies when solo mining. When mining solo, the block reward will show up right away in your wallet, but it won't be in the "unlocked" portion of your balance until 60 more blocks have been mined.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your answer. I now get why there's a chain icon in the table header (see screenshot). :-D It's very simple, yet, being new to all this, I'm still learning the basics, and couldn't totally figure this one out. Thanks again!

Comment: @Quentin Skousen Is there any reference about your description?
Where this and other miracles are described systematically?

Comment: @David: I don't know about "other miracles" but the block maturity setting is a Cryptonote setting, in Monero it is here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/784f7b07f05a645d43f62ed3a9cefda4b0c57825/src/cryptonote_config.h#L43

Comment: @QuentinSkousen thanks, it's code only, and even I read a lot about cryptocurrency there is always some basic-knowledge missing, even it never might be important for trading or mining. That's what I mean with miracles ;-)
Just tried to explain cryptocurrency on a very basic level to my wife - it's a hard challenge :D But if I imagine a few questions I couldn't answer, as most knowledge from articles is quite abstract.

Comment: @David a guide to the workings of a Monero is something that has been talked about quite a bit recently, but at the moment does not exist. It would be very nice to have.